# How to an Array List from least to greatest?

Tags: java

I want to make an arraylist that has random numbers and make it in order from least to greatest.

How do I do this?

Comment: Start by opening an IDE

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yeah I don't really get the problem

Comment: Look on the Internet how to generate random numbers, how to assign values to list elements, and how to sort arrays. Then combine relevant parts into a single program.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the

```
Collections.sort(your_array_name)
```

This sorts your array from least to greatest in place.

If you still want some more information, try this link:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collections-sort-java-examples/